# How do I save embeded docs without error "key $__ must not start with '$'(…)" while using devtool and Mongoose 4.x

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am in the process of upgrading from mongoose 3.8.22 to 4.x
Everything seemed to be working nicely until I started debugging an issue with devtool which I have been using without issue for month while using mongoose 3.8.22.

While running my node server I do not encounter any errors or problems however when running my server using the npm package 'devtool' any save which includes sub-documents fails with the following error:

"key $__ must not start with '$'(…)".

Has anyone experienced this issue or found a fix?

As an example:

I start with 2 schemas, person and customOpts

```
var CustomOptions = new Schema({
    optsType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    someOption: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});
var Person = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    customOpts: [CustomOptions]
});
```

Next I create x new customOpts and add them to a new person

```
var newOpts = new locator.db.customOptions({
    optsType: 'some_opts',
    someOption: true,
});

var newPerson = new locator.db.person({
    name: 'Steve',
    customOpts: [newOpts]
});
```

When using newPerson.save() I have no issues on node but devtool throws the error as long as I have newOpts in the customOpts array

Comment: Do you have a model defined with `CustomOptions` schema?

Comment: Yes,using db.connection.once we set db.customOptions = db.connection.model('customOptions', TestSchemas.CustomOptions);

Comment: Have you tried saving the `customOpts` array as an array of objects not Mongoose documents as `var newOpts = {
    optsType: 'some_opts',
    someOption: true
}; var newPerson = new locator.db.person({
    name: 'Steve',
    customOpts: [newOpts]
});`?

Comment: when forcing toObject on the documents it will work however this is a pretty small example to demonstrate the issue. The application is much more complex so it would be quite the task rewriting/testing to ensure correctness although that might be the only option

Comment: Because you have defined in your `Person` schema the `customOpts` field as an array of `[CustomOptions]` schemas, the most logical thing to do is adding to the array objects that have the same `CustomOptions` schema. Another option would be to make `customOpts` as an array of references to the options model as `customOpts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CustomOptions' }]` where you can save the array as `_id`s.